# How to calculate HttpWebRequest spent outbound and inbound internet traffic

Tags: c#, wpf, httpwebrequest, webrequest, network-traffic

I have the below function to fetch a page. My question is i want to calculate how much internet connection is spent

Both inbound (download) and outbound traffic (sent)

How can i do that ? Thank you

My function

```
 public static string func_fetch_Page(string srUrl, int irTimeOut = 60,
    string srRequestUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0",
    string srProxy = null)
    {
        string srBody = "";
        string srResult = "";
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(srUrl);

            request.Timeout = irTimeOut * 1000;
            request.UserAgent = srRequestUserAgent;
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";

            WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = request.Headers;
            myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Accept-Language", "en-gb,en;q=0.5");
            myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");

            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream strumien = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strumien))
                    {
                        srBody = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        srResult = "success";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch ()
        {

        }

        return srBody;
    }
```

C# .net 4.5 WPF application

@Simon Mourier how do i calculate spent traffic

```
public static long long_GlobalDownload_KByte = 0;
public static long long_GlobalSent_KByte = 0;

Time  _timer_fetch_download_upload = new Timer(getDownload_Upload_Values, null, 0, 100 * 1000);

public static void getDownload_Upload_Values(Object state)
{
    using (Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
    {
        foreach (var cnx in TcpConnection.GetAll().Where(c => c.ProcessId == p.Id))
        {
            Interlocked.Add(ref long_GlobalDownload_KByte, Convert.ToInt64(cnx.DataBytesIn));
            Interlocked.Add(ref long_GlobalSent_KByte, Convert.ToInt64(cnx.DataBytesOut));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you already explored this, but is `System.Net` tracing not an option?

Comment: @Mrchief how do you do that ? can you post answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a proxy using [FiddlerCore](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore) (just a single dll to reference) and set a *WebProxy* to your HttpWebRequest to count the sent and received bytes

```
public class WebConnectionStats
{
    static int _Read = 0;
    static int _Written = 0;

    public static void Init(bool registerAsSystemProxy = false)
    {
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.OnReadRequestBuffer += (s, e) => Interlocked.Add(ref _Written, e.iCountOfBytes);
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.OnReadResponseBuffer += (s, e) => Interlocked.Add(ref _Read, e.iCountOfBytes);
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(8088, registerAsSystemProxy, true);
    }

    public static int Read
    {
        get { return _Read; }
    }

    public static int Written
    {
        get { return _Written; }
    }
}
```

---

```
WebConnectionStats.Init(); //call this only once

var client = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://stackoverflow.com") as HttpWebRequest;
client.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8088);
var resp = client.GetResponse();
var html = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

Console.WriteLine("Read: {0}   Write: {1}", WebConnectionStats.Read, 
                                            WebConnectionStats.Written);
```

**PS1:** This counts will not include the *Tcp Headers'* length

**PS2:** You can get more info about Fiddler core [here](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore)

Comment: ty for answer however this restricts my settings a lot. For example i can't define user-agent or gzip, deflate features which impacts a lot bandwith.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG you can still use HttpWebRequest and any headers, WebClient was just a simplified example. (Just set httpWebRequest.Proxy )

Comment: ah that makes sense i will try i hope this one works :D

Comment: I believe i will get dll from your link ty

Comment: Ty very much again. I just did setup and tried stackoverflow and i get values as read = 97 , write = 225456 . I believe read is outbound traffic and write is inbound am i correct ? also when i check with my firefox firebug i see this numbers not matching very well : http://img.ctrlv.in/img/14/09/14/5415b9cc2e92c.png or they shouldn't match ? how can i verify spent traffic :D Google chrome displayed 218kb it seems like matching :)

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG **1-** I corrected the *read* and *written* bytes in the answer (just the reverse :)). **2-** When you monitor your traffic from your browser, it will also include all images and javascripts references in that page, just monitor only your WebRequest. (BTW: You can use Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to monitor your requests. )

Comment: AWesome after enabling gzip httcompression i almost get same values ty very much :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61214/discussion-between-monstermmorpg-and-ezi).

Comment: this works great however it comes with a great cost. the speed of crawling decreases almost to half :(

Answer (score 7):

One Windows API can give you this information: [GetPerTcpConnectionEStats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb485738.aspx) for IPV4 connections and the associated IPV6 GetPerTcp6ConnectionEStats function. Note you need to use [SetPerTcpConnectionEStats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/bb451840.aspx) before being able to get any stat, and that usually needs admin rights...

To get the list of all connections, you can use the [GetExtendedTcpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa365928.aspx) function. It can also give you the connection's process id which is very useful.

These are native APIs not that easy to use, but I have created a TcpConnection class that wraps all this. It's available here in a small WPF app called IPStats: https://github.com/smourier/IPStats

So, the difficulty here is to link your .NET HttpWebRequest to a TcpConnection from the list of connections.
You can't get any stat before the connection exists, but once you have the connection created, you can get the corresponding one with a code like this:

```
    static IEnumerable<TcpConnection> GetProcessConnection(IPEndPoint ep)
    {
        var p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        return TcpConnection.GetAll().Where(c => ep.Equals(c.RemoteEndPoint) && c.ProcessId == p.Id);
    }

    HttpWebRequest req = ...

    // this is how you can get the enpoint, or you can also built it by yourself manually
    IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint;
    req.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate += (sp, rp, rc) =>
        {
            remoteEndPoint = rp;
            return null;
        };
    // TODO: here, you need to connect, so the connection exists
    var cnx = GetProcessConnection(remoteEndPoint).FirstOrDefault();

    // access denied here means you don't have sufficient rights
    cnx.DataStatsEnabled = true;

    // TODO: here, you need to do another request, so the values are incremented
    // now, you should get non-zero values here
    // note TcpConnection also has int/out bandwidth usage, and in/out packet usage.
    Console.WriteLine("DataBytesIn:" + cnx.DataBytesIn);
    Console.WriteLine("DataBytesOut:" + cnx.DataBytesOut);

    // if you need all connections in the current process, just do this
    ulong totalBytesIn = 0;
    ulong totalBytesOut = 0;
    Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    foreach (var cnx in TcpConnection.GetAll().Where(c => c.ProcessId == p.Id))
    {
        totalBytesIn += cnx.DataBytesIn;
        totalBytesOut += cnx.DataBytesOut;
    }
```

There are 3 drawbacks:

- you need to be admin to enable data stats;
- you can't get the stats for the very first request. This may not be a problem depending on your
  context;
- the matching between the HttpWebRequest's connection and the the TCP connection can be trickier to determine because you can have more than one connection to a remote endpoint, even in the same process. The only way to distinguish is to determine the local endpoint (especially the port) and extend the GetProcessConnection with this local endpoint. Unfortunately, there is no easy way to do this. Here is a related answer about this: [How do I get the local port number of an HttpWebRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211974/how-do-i-get-the-local-port-number-of-an-httpwebrequest)

Update: if you want to continuously monitor all connections for a given process, I've written a ProcessTcpConnections utility class that remembers all connections and sums their usage. It would be used like this (in a console app sample):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProcessTcpConnections p = new ProcessTcpConnections(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
        Timer timer = new Timer(UpdateStats, p, 0, 100);

        do
        {
            // let's activate the network so we measure something...
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadString("http://www.example.com");
            }
            Console.ReadKey(true); // press any key to download again
        }
        while (true);
    }

    private static void UpdateStats(object state)
    {
        ProcessTcpConnections p = (ProcessTcpConnections)state;
        p.Update();
        Console.WriteLine("DataBytesIn:" + p.DataBytesIn + " DataBytesOut:" + p.DataBytesOut);
    }
}

public class ProcessTcpConnections : TcpConnectionGroup
{
    public ProcessTcpConnections(int processId)
        : base(c => c.ProcessId == processId)
    {
        ProcessId = processId;
    }

    public int ProcessId { get; private set; }
}

public class TcpConnectionGroup
{
    private List<TcpConnectionStats> _states = new List<TcpConnectionStats>();
    private Func<TcpConnection, bool> _groupFunc;

    public TcpConnectionGroup(Func<TcpConnection, bool> groupFunc)
    {
        if (groupFunc == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("groupFunc");

        _groupFunc = groupFunc;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        foreach (var conn in TcpConnection.GetAll().Where(_groupFunc))
        {
            if (!conn.DataStatsEnabled)
            {
                conn.DataStatsEnabled = true;
            }

            TcpConnectionStats existing = _states.Find(s => s.Equals(conn));
            if (existing == null)
            {
                existing = new TcpConnectionStats();
                _states.Add(existing);
            }
            existing.DataBytesIn = conn.DataBytesIn;
            existing.DataBytesOut = conn.DataBytesOut;
            existing.LocalEndPoint = conn.LocalEndPoint;
            existing.RemoteEndPoint = conn.RemoteEndPoint;
            existing.State = conn.State;
            existing.LastUpdateTime = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    public ulong DataBytesIn
    {
        get
        {
            ulong count = 0; foreach (var state in _states) count += state.DataBytesIn; return count;
        }
    }

    public ulong DataBytesOut
    {
        get
        {
            ulong count = 0; foreach (var state in _states) count += state.DataBytesOut; return count;
        }
    }

    private class TcpConnectionStats
    {
        public ulong DataBytesIn { get; set; }
        public ulong DataBytesOut { get; set; }
        public IPEndPoint LocalEndPoint { get; set; }
        public IPEndPoint RemoteEndPoint { get; set; }
        public TcpState State { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdateTime { get;  set; }

        public bool Equals(TcpConnection connection)
        {
            return LocalEndPoint.Equals(connection.LocalEndPoint) && RemoteEndPoint.Equals(connection.RemoteEndPoint);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ty for answer. would it be possible to track entire application spent connection traffic ?

Comment: also i checked your software and it doesn't show traffic correctly. maybe because i have installed kaspersky internet security ? and i am confused how to use your class to track my own application traffic :) and can you please modify the code you put in answer and extend it. you didn't use req anywhere so how does it know to scan which one ?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Stats are always per connection, but you can get all TCP connexions for a process since each TcpConnection has a process id. Note: the app is not finished, only the class is ok.

Comment: ty for answer again. i would like to get all traffic inbound and outbound traffic for the running process. can you show how to do it ? And is it cumulative or instance based i mean how will i track it. Does it stack all input and output and whenever i query do i get entire process life time outbound and inbound traffic ? ty very much. I mean lets say i didn't query 5 minutes and there have been 100 tcp connections but all completed and disposed. Do i get those traffic ?

Comment: I have updated my answer will all the connections in the current process. If connections are gone, their traffic will not be measured. Most of the time, there is a delay between the client disconnect and the real disconnect, but if you want this information, you'll have to build a timer, identify all connections at each tick, and sum whats needs to be.

Comment: Ok i added the application as you said and make the check interval per 50 seconds however i am still reading a lot higher values than what kaspersky internet security and windows 8.1 resource monitor shows as average. So how can i fix this issue ? I suppose application keep returning same values again and again, totally depended on how quick you check values. I am using your code below  // if you need all connections in the current process, just do this. Edited my question for you to show how do i calculate values. i know they are byte so i divide by 1024 to get kb.

Comment: I am so close to answer. How can i get accurate traffic of entire application with using your class :( ty very much

Comment: Simon the traffic i get totally changes by the frequency i check. So it is misleading. How can i get correct data can you show example ?

Comment: If connections in a given process are stable, the frequency should not matter. You just take the last values (you don't have to sum anything). Polling is only useful to ensure you remember connections that were killed. Not sure what's your problem. Maybe if you share a repro we can have a look at it.

Comment: Simon i edited my question and displayed how i get values. I really do not understand what you mean. I don't need to sum anything how is that ? Can you please update your answer and show me how should i get values for entire application accurately. Assume that this application will run forever and there will be constantly new tcp connections because it is a crawler.

Comment: ty for updated answer. however i am getting this error any idea why ? application is running as administrator on a administrator account win 8.1 : http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2014/253/5/f/error_by_monstermmorpg-d7ynvi7.png

Comment: Simon it is giving error can you please upload your working console application to somewhere

Comment: The whole app is there http://pastebin.com/K20RFK4b (plus you need the TcpConnection from the github project). Access denied means you don't have enough rights.

Comment: Wow Simon i know it says i don't have enough rights however i do have. I am running on a full access admin account on win 8.1. Can you please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Simon can you please help me here i want to reward this bounty to you

Comment: Well, there's no much more to say. Access denied is a rights problem. I'm also running Windows 8.1. Have you disabled UAC?

Comment: Is it doing that with my small console app sample, as is, w/o any modification?

Comment: yes here my whole application : http://www.4shared.com/zip/Jv63f-7vba/ConsoleApplication1.html

Comment: This link requires me to login, please find a normal download place

Comment: Sorry about that i thought it wasn't requiring this one works i tried : https://www.sendspace.com/file/uzoe5f

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to know *exactly* how much network traffic is occurring because of some unpredictable Ethernet traffic and that sort of thing, but essentially the gist of any HTTP request is:

```
method request-uri version
* (header : value)
CRLF
body
```

Given that, you can calculate out how long the request string will be:

```
HttpWebRequest req = ...;
StringBuilder requestText = new StringBuilder();

requestText.AppendFormat("{0} {1} HTTP/{2}.{3}", req.Method, req.RequestUri, req.ProtocolVersion.Major, req.ProtocolVersion.Minor);

requestText.AppendLine();

foreach (var header in req.Headers)
{
    requestText.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}", v, webReq.Headers[v]);
    requestText.AppendLine();
}

requestText.AppendLine();

// somehow add on the contents of the request stream, or just add that length later. I won't put that in this code because of stream positioning and all that

return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(requestText.ToString());
```

Then it's pretty similar for the response side. The format for an HTTP response is:

```
version status-code status-description
* (header : value)
CRLF
body
```

So,

```
HttpWebResponse resp = ...;
StringBuilder responseText = new StringBuilder();

responseText .AppendFormat("HTTP/{0}.{1} {2} {3}", resp.ProtocolVersion.Major, resp.ProtocolVersion.Minor, (int)resp.StatusCode, resp.StatusDescription);
responseText .AppendLine();

foreach (var header in resp.Headers)
{
    responseText .AppendFormat("{0}: {1}", v, resp.Headers[v]);
    responseText .AppendLine();
}

responseText.AppendLine();
```

Here, there's a bit of a decision to be made. You need to get the length of the response body. There might be more options, but what I'm thinking now are that you could:

1. Write a `Stream` wrapper that grabs the number of bytes copied. That way you don't have to worry about chunked transfers, and it could be kind of fun to write.
2. Use the `content-length` header, although then you won't get it if there *isn't* that header, as is the case for `transfer-encoding: chunked`.
3. Read the stream using whatever method you want, then add the length of that in.
4. Copy the stream to a `MemoryStream`, then pass that off as the new response stream whilst grabbing the length on the way.

That all said, you have the *extra* frustration of worrying about content compression. I see you use it in yours, in fact. Given simplicity, I'm going to assume GZip and go with the fourth option. You might want to expand on what I write here to make it a little more comprehensive.

```
// webReq.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.None; is required for this, since we're handling that decompression ourselves.

using (var respStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    respStream.CopyTo(memStream);

    using (var gzip = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(respStream, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(gzip))
    {
        var content = reader.ReadToEnd();

        // you may or may not actually care about this, depending on whether this is just light testing or if you'll actually have these metrics in production
    }

    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(responseText.ToString()) + memStream.Length;
}
```

Now, a few caveats that I'm seeing as I look now. Others might notice more, and I'll add them in if people comment.

- As I mentioned way back at the start of this, there can be more network traffic from one request than this will tell you.
- Depending on the client and server, you could find that actual headers could be listed with a different number of spaces. I don't believe that's beyond the HTTP spec, and even if it is people will do it. So there's a chance, for random example, that you'll see one server set `content-type: text/html` and another set `content-type : text/html`. There's *at least* (well, exactly, since we're using UTF-8) one byte difference. Again, little, but that's a possible discrepancy.

This is just an estimate. It's a good one, but it's just an estimate.

If you're looking for extra accuracy at the cost of some simplicity, you could also write yourself a proxy. The idea of an HTTP proxy is that it simply gets the verbatim request, so it's "super easy" to then get the length. The biggest issue, of course, is that you then have to write a fully functioning proxy that, in all likelihood, parses and re-requests your incoming requests, and parses and relays all their respective responses. Certainly doable, but it's non-trivial. Particularly if you have to worry about SSL.

At the most basic level, of course, you could write, in essence, an alternative to a program like WireShark. I wouldn't know how to do that, and I wouldn't suggest you bother unless you *really* need it. That still wouldn't give you a perfect idea, either. Just closer.

And now, that all said, and boy, that was quite a bit said, if you're doing this for the purposes of profiling, there's a good chance the tools built into Visual Studio will let you do it. Admittedly I'm far from knowledgeable on them--I've never even opened them--but I believe there are network-traffic profilers available. Of course, I doubt they work on every platform like this would. But that would certainly be an easier approach.

*Also, if anyone happens to notice any typos in here, I did copy-paste a couple times and I think I got them all, but feel free to let me know or just fix them.*

Comment: well i am doing this for the sake of logging how much traffic my application used. from your answer i don't get how does it calculate gzipped or deflated answer spent traffic ?. Can you please modify my function and write your answer fully ? Modified version of my function that does calculate the traffic. Ty very much.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. That's what the third block of C# does.

Comment: You see my function at the post ? Cany you take it modify and post as a full function in the very below your answer ? Ty very much

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG This is really meant to be its own method, for the most part. You'll want to write your data to a `MemoryStream` kind of like I did with the response traffic, but the opposite. Write to a `MemoryStream`, then `CopyTo` from that to the request stream.

Answer (score 3):

it bit ugly but you can use network tracing and then parse the log.
see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824(v=vs.110).aspx for enable network tracing

i add basic code ( i know that i have bug in parsing the log but the idea should be clear )

**NetworkListner.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace NetworkTracing
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of NetworkListner.
    /// </summary>
    public class NetworkListner : TraceListener
    {
        public static int BytesSent { get; private set;} 
        public static int BytesReceived { get; private set;}
        private bool _inSend = false;
        private bool _inReceived = false;
        private string _lastMessage = "";
        private Regex _lengthRegex = new Regex(@"(\[\d*\]) ([\dA-F]*)");
        public NetworkListner()
        {
            BytesSent = 0;
            BytesReceived = 0;          
        }

        private int ExtractNumOfBytes(string message){
            string lengthUntilThisLineStr = null;
            try {           
                var match = _lengthRegex.Match(message);                
                lengthUntilThisLineStr = match.Groups[2].Value;
            } catch (ArgumentException ex) {
                // Syntax error in the regular expression
            }
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(lengthUntilThisLineStr)) {
                return 0;
            }
            var lengthUntilThisLine = int.Parse(lengthUntilThisLineStr,NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            return lengthUntilThisLine;
        }

        public override void Write(string message) {
            if (message.Equals("System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : ")) {
                return;
            }
            if (message.Contains("Exiting Socket#")) {
                int bytes = ExtractNumOfBytes(_lastMessage);
                if (_inSend) {
                    _inSend = false;
                    BytesSent += bytes;
                }else if (_inReceived) {
                    _inReceived = false;
                    BytesReceived += bytes;
                }   
            }           
            else if (message.Contains("Data from Socket")){
                if (message.Contains("Send")) {
                    _inSend = true;
                }
                else if (message.Contains("Receive")) {
                    _inReceived = true;
                }
            }
            _lastMessage = message;
        }

        public override void WriteLine(string message) {
            Write(message + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace NetworkTracing
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {           
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0";
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream strumien = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strumien))
                    {
                        var res = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine("Send -> {0}",NetworkListner.BytesSent);
                        Console.WriteLine("Recieve -> {0}",NetworkListner.BytesReceived);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**App.config**

```
<configuration>
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.Net.Sockets" tracemode="includehex" maxdatasize="1024">
        <listeners>
          <add name="network"/>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
     <switches>
      <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>      
    </switches>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="network"
        type="NetworkTracing.NetworkListner, NetworkTracing"
      />
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true"/>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

you also need to compile your project with trace flag ( this flag is default in debug ) by :

1. With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu
2. click Properties.
3. Click the Compile tab.
4. Click the Advanced Compile Options button to open the Advanced
   Compiler Settings dialog box.
5. Select the Define TRACE constant check box, and then click OK.

Comment: give me full answer with example and proper code showing how to trace traffic and i will accept yours.

Comment: Unfortunately, logs from network tracing don't give that data sent/received information. It can dump the whole payload, tell you it when it connects, etc. but it won't tell you how much it sent or received. You can have a look at the main fonction here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Logging.cs#610ea3882b1e9b59 it doesn't traces what's interesting...

Comment: how is your code getting only my application i don't see any specificity it seems like getting whole OS traffic

Comment: it get only your application traffic because the NetworkListner config only in your application app.config ( you **can't** capture other applications traffic )

Comment: and for release you must to compile with trace flag

Comment: assume that there are thousands of connections happening simultaneously. How will get correct total traffic ? will this return only that particular function call spent traffic ?   and how do i add this trace flag ? Console.WriteLine("Send -> {0}",NetworkListner.BytesSent);

Answer (score 1):

If your client app is communicating with your known IIS server(s), then I would try getting this data from the IIS logs. Check out the cs-bytes (client to server bytes aka request bytes) and sc-bytes (server to client bytes aka response).  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754702(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Nope not getting data from IIS it is a local APP. ty for suggestion however. I dont get this. Many applications i see is displaying spent traffic are they all coding traffic sniffers ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use **.NET CLR Networking** performance counter as it can give you sent and received bytes per AppDomain

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70xadeyt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

I wrote a Helper class to verify the accuracy and the results are similar to Windows ResourceMonitor, so I believe the accuracy should be acceptable.

**How to Use:**

here is the Helper class:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

public class NetworkMonitor
{
    private PerformanceCounter _bytesSent;
    private PerformanceCounter _bytesReceived;
    private readonly int _processId;
    private bool _initialized;

    public NetworkMonitor(int processID)
    {
        _processId = processID;
        Initialize();
    }

    public NetworkMonitor()
        : this(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id)
    {

    }
    private void Initialize()
    {
        if (_initialized)
            return;

        var category = new PerformanceCounterCategory(".NET CLR Networking 4.0.0.0");
        var instanceNames = category.GetInstanceNames().Where(i => i.Contains(string.Format("p{0}", _processId)));
        if (!instanceNames.Any()) return;

        _bytesSent = new PerformanceCounter
        {
            CategoryName = ".NET CLR Networking 4.0.0.0",
            CounterName = "Bytes Sent",
            InstanceName = instanceNames.First(),
            ReadOnly = true
        };

        _bytesReceived = new PerformanceCounter
        {
            CategoryName = ".NET CLR Networking 4.0.0.0",
            CounterName = "Bytes Received",
            InstanceName = instanceNames.First(),
            ReadOnly = true
        };

        _initialized = true;
    }

    public float GetSentBytes()
    {
        Initialize(); //in Net4.0 performance counter will get activated after first request
        return _initialized ? _bytesSent.RawValue : 0;
    }
    enter code here
    public float GetReceivedBytes()
    {
        Initialize(); //in Net4.0 performance counter will get activated after first request
        return _initialized ? _bytesReceived.RawValue : 0;
    }
}
```

you should add this part to your app.config

```
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <performanceCounters enabled="true" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>
```

and here is the sample I used to verify accuracy based on your own method:

```
   private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var netMonitor = new NetworkMonitor();

            var received = netMonitor.GetReceivedBytes();
            var sent = netMonitor.GetSentBytes();

            Console.WriteLine("received:{0}, sent:{1}", received, sent);
            func_fetch_Page("http://www.google.com");

            received = netMonitor.GetReceivedBytes();
            sent = netMonitor.GetSentBytes();

            Console.WriteLine("received:{0}, sent:{1}", received, sent);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```